# Read Memo from shared mailbox in using graph.microsoft.com

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

I have developed a solution that can download selected memo in mime format and process it (solution works as an addin in outlook web/client).

I fetch data from emails like this (with graph or api v2.0)

[https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{uuid}/$value](https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/%7Buuid%7D/$value)

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/${uuid}/$value](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/$%7Buuid%7D/$value)

However when I try to get an email from shared mailbox it fails

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId",
        "message": "Item '*******************GAAAAAABWtYncIxJ9Tr9kkgiMGaNGBwDLj7SD7a9lRI0-8mlYFHqoAAAAAAEMAADPq6uIKft4RaiCqD-1XViEAALJ75k9AAA=' doesn't belong to the targeted mailbox 'a8****67-****-****-****-c7d8****5b2c'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-03-31T09:21:08",
            "request-id": "189dc3f3-4813-4974-a873-bda9cb799636",
            "client-request-id": "189dc3f3-4813-4974-a873-bda9cb799636"
        }
    }
}
```

My account has access to shared mailbox in UI (client/web app) however via API it's not working.

Is there a proper way to solve my need?

Comment: Hey, please refer to this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-share-messages-folders . This has a detailed explanation of how to fetch mails from a shared mail box.

Comment: @outlookadd-insTeam-MSFT thanks for reply. In the article it says:

> If John has signed into your app and provided delegated permissions (Mail.Read.Shared or Mail.ReadWrite.Shared)

What does it mean - signed into your app? Can't I use just my own App/API that already fetching data?

Comment: @outlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I am also using https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{uuid}/$value to download a memo - and it is not wokring as well. Does it make any difference to use Grahp or direct API request?

Comment: So, are you able to get these message from Shared Mailbox using only Microsoft Graph API directly (without using any outlook addin APIs)?

Microsoft Graph Explorer can be used for this: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer